# Getting "Missing or malformed Token" while using gofiber firebase-auth

Tags: firebase, go, firebase-authentication, go-fiber

I am trying to run [Gofiber firebase-auth](https://github.com/gofiber/recipes/tree/master/firebase-auth). I have generated a private key from Firebase Console, **Settings -> Service Account -> Generate new private key** and have given the file path to:

**.env**:

```
GOOGLE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT = 'C:/Users/Desktop/flutter-demo.json'
WEB_API_KEY = "<API_KEY>"  // from config section of general settings at firebase console
TEST_USER_EMAIL = "test@test.com"
TEST_USER_PASSWORD = "test123"
```

which is used in **main.go**:

```
serviceAccount, fileExi := os.LookupEnv("GOOGLE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT")
opt := option.WithCredentialsFile(serviceAccount)
```

But, on accessing any of the Authenticated Routes, I'm getting:

```
Missing or malformed Token
```

Can anyone please help, maybe I'm doing some mistake or missing something from the docs

Answer (score 0):

Hi below is an example of using gofiber firebase auth,

https://github.com/gofiber/recipes/tree/master/firebase-auth

Hope this will help you. Thanks

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. Yeah I have been following the same link. I have mentioned the same in my question too, but it's still not working..

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to **Sachintha**, one needs to send an Authorization Header token from login with the user name and password, as go firebase auth just a middleware to check whether endpoints are authenticated and it does not provide any authentication or user login.